# Sinatra initialize a namespace controller

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Under the commands folder, I'd like to initialize a controller
but Sinatra reports this error in the logs

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)

```
/home/daniel/sinatraApi/app/commands/authenticate_user.rb:6:in `initialize'
/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:86:in `new'
2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:147:in `to_app'
config.ru:15:in `inner_app'
/
```

The controllers are called

```
use AuthenticateUser
run ApplicationController
```

I've tried to add

```
use Commands::AuthenticateUser
```

or require

```
require "./app/commands/authenticate_user"
```

on config.ru

```
Authenticate_user

require 'jwt'
#require './app/controllers/application'
class AuthenticateUser
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(email, password)
    @email = email
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) if user
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :email, :password

  def user
    user = User.find_by_email(email)
    return user if user && user.authenticate(password)

    errors.add :user_authentication, 'invalid credentials'
    nil
  end
end
```

How can I setup the namespace or nested controllers in Sinatra?

Comment: Can you show the code in `authenticate_user.rb`?

Comment: Sure, @maxpleaner the quenstion is updated with authenticate_user.rb

Comment: Is there supposed to be `Authenticate_user` and `AuthenticateUser` in there? If so, where does `Authenticate_user` come from?